# parameters with quotes and without quotes with same name javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new at javascript and i am following a tutorial so anyone explain me this syntax because it seems to me bit different than the other tutorial

```
 abc.setOfName("nameSet").xyz("Name", Name);
```

why using '.' and argument with quotes and without quotes xyz("Name",Name)

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Stackoverflow is to solve problems, no to explain people the language, you should start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Answer (score 3):

```
abc.setOfName("nameSet").xyz("Name", Name);
//            ^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^  ^^^^
//             \ string literal /        \ identifier
```

`"nameSet"` and `"Name"` are literal strings. `Name` is an *identifier* (the name of a variable, argument, or similar). So is `abc`. Somewhere prior to the code above, `Name` would need to be defined and initialized (as would `abc`).

The `.` is called a *property accessor*. The one in `abc.setOfName` means "get the property called `setOfName` from the object referenced by `abc`." The next one, `.xyz`, is accessing the property `xyz` on whatever it is that `setOfName` returns when called.

The `()` in that example trigger a function call. That is, `abc.setOfName(...)` *calls* the function that `setOfName` refers to.

So here's what that line does:

1. Gets the current value of `abc` (remember, it's a variable, or function argument, or similar; `abc` is the identifier that, um, identifies it)
2. Looks up the property `setOfName` on it and gets its value
3. Assumes that value is a function reference and calls it, passing in the literal string `"nameSet"`
4. When that function call returns, looks up the `xyz` property on whatever it returns
5. Gets the current value of `Name`
6. Assumes the value from Step 4 is a function reference and calls it, passing in the literal string `"Name"` and the value from Step 5

Comment: you forgot to explain abc, the `.` and the parentheses

Comment: @webdeb: Yeah, I missed that part. I actually missed both those parts individually. :-) Thanks.